# Azure Search SDK Create DataSource

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I've been created a datasource by Azure Search SDK.

The Datasource from Azure sql which is a View.

I tyr to setting the DataChangeDetectionPolicy and DataDeletionDetectionPolicy,
but i can't understand how to set this two property.

When i think this two property doesn't supported on the preview sdk,so i try to use REST API to solve this.

I read the article:
[MSDN Create Data Source (Azure Search Service REST API)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn946876.aspx)

And use Chrome Extension Postman to set the Data Change Detection Policies.

Url : https://domain.search.windows.net/datasources/temp1?api-version=2015-02-28

body :

```
{ 
    "@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",
    "highWaterMarkColumnName" : "ModifiedDatetime" 
}
```

then i get the 400 bad request .

error message:

```
 {
   "error": 
  {
   "code": "",
   "message": "The request is invalid. Details: dataSource : Incompatible type kinds were found. The type 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy' was found to be of kind 'Complex' instead of the expected kind 'Entity'.\r\n"
  }
 }
```

So,i have two questions.

1.Is the SDK are not support this function Now?

2.with the REST API , how to solve the error?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [official article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers-2015-02-28/), the way to create the datasource for SQL integration for Views is:

```
{ 
    "name" : "myazuresqldatasource",
    "type" : "azuresql",
    "credentials" : { "connectionString" : "connection string" },
    "container" : { "name" : "table or view name" }, 
    "dataChangeDetectionPolicy" : {
       "@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",
       "highWaterMarkColumnName" : "[a row version or last_updated column name]" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SDK does support data source creation. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.datasource